# Unable to upload to App Store with Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, app-store, app-store-connect

When trying to upload an app to App Store in Xcode (7.1) I'm prompted with this error message:

> iTunes Store operation failed. You are not authorised to use this
>   service.

---

### The steps I go through when trying to upload

1. Product -> Archive which completes successfully
2. Window -> Organizer where I select my app in the left pane.
   I then choose my most recent archive, press "Upload to App
   Store..." and pick the relevant development team.

At that point I'm prompted with the error message "iTunes Store operation failed. You are not authorized to use this service for provider: "

I find this odd as my account in the chosen team has admin rights.

My account is also added to the team in iTunes Connect, where my roles are set to App Manager, Reports and Sales.

---

### Attempts to solve the issue

I have:

1. Deleted my account in Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts and added it
   again.
2. Generated a new archive after deleting and re-adding my account in
   Xcode.
3. Restarted Xcode.
4. Opened Application Loader via Xcode -> Open Developer Tool ->
   Application Loader. This seems to have helped many others running into similar issues. I can, however, not login due to this:

> Your user account is attached to several iTunes providers. Create
>   separate accounts for each provider before logging in.

---

At the moment I'm out of ideas on what might cause the issue, let alone how to solve it. Do you have any?

Comment: I get this error as well after adding a second provider to my long standing iTunes Connect account today.

Comment: I am also having this issue. @Maxdvlpr, did you solve the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't @DancOfDeth. I had to upload with the app owner's account. A workaround that might help, though, is to upload as Admin. If appropriate, ask the app owner to upgrade your role.

Comment: I am having the same issue ("Your user account is attached to several iTunes providers...."). Anyone have any update on how to resolve this issue aside from having to create another user under the same account? BTW, just updated to latest Xcode 7.3 today, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've faced the same issue (account is attached to several iTunes providers) when I've downloaded Application Loader from iTunes Connect. The link on iTunes Connect download the version 3.0 of application loader that not supports multi-accounts.

To download the latest version and use multi-accounts you should download the latest version of Xcode. Application Loader is part of Xcode (Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader). You can download Xcode directly from the Mac App Store.

For more information on this delivery mechanism, see the [Application Loader User Guide](http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader).

Comment: you saved my life bro. hope i could make your answer the best one.

Comment: Spent several hours trying to upload a build in iTunes connect until found your answer. After read your answer it was piece of cake

Answer (score 7):

I have found a workaround to this issue. Go to iTunes connect and login with the admin itunes connect account. Create a new apple id with a new email account. Make that account the admin under users and roles.

After that sign in at least once to your new itunes connect account. Then proceed your app submission with application loader with the new account. I was facing the exact same issue and i fixed it this way!

Comment: Brother, when you copy answer from other forums, do not forget to give appropriate credits. Same answer before 6 hours of your this answer by `ribera`  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26264

Comment: That is my apple dev account bro :D

Comment: That's a strange name Niraj. Not judging :) Sorry to bother.

Answer (score 3):

Ben's answer notes this, but I want to call it out:

**Make sure the bundle id of your app matches the expected bundle id in iTunes Connect.**

This error message occurred for me when the bundle ids did not match.

Comment: Similarly, I did get this error when I forgot to create the app in iTunes Connect. I only set up the bundle ID in the Member Center and then tried to upload a build. After creating the app in iTunes Connect, the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

The `Your user account is attached to several iTunes providers. Create separate accounts for each provider before logging in.` error seems to be a limitation/mismatch between Xcode and the new multi-provider/provider switching feature introduced to iTunes Connect on 11/13/2015.

To get around it, make sure you've already created the app you are trying to submit in iTunes Connect under the correct provider. You'll also need to make sure the bundle ID matches on the archived app and the record for it you create in iTC.

Additionally, your account must have the developer, app manager or admin role to be able to successfully upload builds.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Ben Lachman. The app was already created in iTunes Connect and my role was indeed set to App Manager (and Reports, and Sales). Weird stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I switched the project from manual managed signing, to automatically manage signing the issue hit me (I'd done this to add a new device for testing) - switching back to manual signing fixed the issue.