# Your Apple ID account is also attached to other iTunes providers

Tags: ios

I am getting this problem when trying to login to application loader.

"Your Apple ID account is also attached to other iTunes providers. You will need to create a new user on iTunes Connect to submit content to this account. Please contact us if you have questions or need help."

Can any on help me how to solve this issue???

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to upload to App Store with Xcode 7.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807476/unable-to-upload-to-app-store-with-xcode-7-1)

Answer (score 15):

Application Loader, which I downloaded from developer portal, does show this error.

But Application Loader that comes with Xcode, worked fine.

Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader

Answer (score 2):

I did fixed it without creating or changing accounts. It worked for me because I had pending agreements on ITC.

I first went to [itunesconnect.apple.com](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) and I revised my pending agreements, I had this pending:
[image]
I added some extra info and got an email from apple. I refreshed ITC and the error was gone.

Then I opened application loader via Xcode: Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader, and I could login again.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah ,the account you in which you have paid , that means your developer account. It is the one in which is to be used in application loader. Other account cannot be access using yours.

Secondly your developer account work in everywhere

1) developer.apple.com 

2) itunes.connect

3) application loader 

4) also in  creating build through Xcode